# assign the value of `input ` to a variable but return blank in JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

I want to assign the value of `input`  to a variable in Javascript, but I am not sure why the value of `input` is always blank.

Here is an example:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input').value
let val = 'not'

function check() {
  //console.log(document.getElementById('input').value) will work
  console.log(typeof input)
  console.log(input)

}
```

```html
<input id='input' type='text'>
<button onclick='check()'>Check</button>
```

The `input` value is blank (nothing), but the `typeof input` is `string`.

If I use `document.getElementById('input').value`, this will totally work which will display the value of `input` sucessfully.

Could anyone explain me a little bit why I assign it to a `variable` won't work?

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: You're assigning the variable when the page first loads, not after the user clicks the button.

Comment: Put the assignment into the `check` function and it will work.

Comment: @Barmar, Oh it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable assignment `val = 'not'` takes place at the first time page load. When you need to assign dynamic value, like on a button click, you need an event handling mechanism (In your case, a `click` event). You are calling a function upon click, but not assigning any value to your variable there. Make assignment inside function like:

```js
function check() {
  val = document.getElementById('input').value
  console.log(val)
}
```